# In which verses, if any, is the word ܨܘܘܬܐ used in the Syriac Peshitta Bible?

Tags: word-study, aramaic, layers-of-meaning, peshitta, syriac

Also, does this word have a different meaning in Syriac when compared to other dialects of Aramaic?

Comment: A search for ܨܘܘܬܐ and צוותא seems to indicate no occurrence in the Tanakh or Peshitta, only in Targums and Midrash.

Comment: The infinitive צוות of the root צות does show up in the Tanakh.

Comment: The lemma ܨܬ does show up in the Peshitta in John 3:29, Acts 2:14; and 8:6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search for ܨܘܘܬܐ and צוותא seems to indicate no occurrence in the Tanakh or Peshitta, only in Targums and Midrash. The infinitive צוות of the root צוה does show up in the Tanakh.  The lemma ܨܬ does show up in the Peshitta in John 3:29, Acts 2:14; and 8:6.

> , ܨܴܬ݂    Verb.  Gloss: *heed; listen to*.  Root: ܨܬ.  Inflected form marked as Lexeme: ܨܴܬ݂.  Index of Inflected Forms: ܨܬ.
> --
> Kiraz, G. A. (2003). In *Analytical lexicon of the Syriac New Testament: based on the SEDRA 3 Database of George Anton Kiraz*. Logos Bible Software.

> [צָוָה ... vb.Pi. *lay charge (upon), give charge (to), charge, command, order*
> --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In *Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon* (p. 845). Clarendon Press.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that צוותא means connect in Aramaic. If it is used in the Targums, then what corresponding word does the Peshitta use in those verses?

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if Syriac has a different word for connect than other dialects of Aramaic, and if so what is it?

Comment: We need to find the Syriac root.